# Python: Parsing a colon delimited file with various counts of fields

Tags: python, parsing, file, delimiter

I'm trying to parse a a few files with the following format in 'clientname'.txt

```
hostname:comp1
time: Fri Jan 28 20:00:02 GMT 2011
ip:xxx.xxx.xx.xx
fs:good:45
memory:bad:78
swap:good:34
Mail:good
```

Each section is delimited by a : but where lines 0,2,6 have 2 fields... lines 1,3-5 have 3 or more fields. (A big issue I've had trouble with is the time: line, since 20:00:02 is really a time and not 3 separate fields.

I have several files like this that I need to parse. There are many more lines in some of these files with multiple fields.

```
...
for i in clients:
if os.path.isfile(rpt_path + i + rpt_ext):          # if the rpt exists then do this
    rpt = rpt_path + i + rpt_ext
    l_count = 0
    for line in open(rpt, "r"):
        s_line = line.rstrip()
        part = s_line.split(':')
        print part
        l_count = l_count + 1
else:                                               # else break
    break
```

First I'm checking if the file exists first, if it does then open the file and parse it (eventually) As of now I'm just printing the output (print part) to make sure it's parsing right.
Honestly, the only trouble I'm having at this point is the time: field. How can I treat that line specifically different than all the others? The time field is ALWAYS the 2nd line in all of my report files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `time` is a special case, you could do:

```
[...]
s_line = line.rstrip()
if line.startswith('time:'):
    part = s_line.split(':', 1)
else:
    part = s_line.split(':')
print part
[...]
```

This would give you:

```
['hostname', 'comp1']
['time', ' Fri Jan 28 20:00:02 GMT 2011']
['ip', 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx']
['fs', 'good', '45']
['memory', 'bad', '78']
['swap', 'good', '34']
['Mail', 'good']
```

And doesn't rely on the position of `time` in the file.

Comment: Awesome, that did it :) I suppose my next question would be how can I refer to the "new" fields as they are put out? I.E. If I next wanted to print out just the time itself? would it be something like part[1] or part(1)? Or more specifically how do I find out how many fields each list has?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: and what happens if there is a `timeout : 987` or a `timer : off` line? What's that leading space on the front of the time data?

Comment: Better still would be `if line.startswith('time:')` , to prevent 'timers:foo:bar' being matched.

Comment: @John Machin: You must have submitted that as I started typing. Updated my answer accrodingly.

Comment: There is a leading space in the example above. This could be removed if required.

Answer (score 2):

split method has the following syntax `split(   [sep [,maxsplit]])` and if the maxsplit is given, it will make maxsplit+1 parts. In you case, you just have give maxsplit as 1. Just `split(':',1)` would solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that at first but in the cases where the line is Swap:Good:39 it returns ['Swap', 'Good:39']

Comment: @Mark, if date is the only one causing this problem then you can check `if 'time' in line: part = s_line.split(':',1)` otherwise use the normal split.

Answer (score 1):

Design considerations:

Robustly handle extraneous whitespace, including blank lines, and missing colons.

Extract a record_type, which is then used to decide how to parse the remainder of the line.

```
>>> def munched(s, n=None):
...     if n is None:
...         n = 99999999 # this kludge should not be necessary
...     return [x.strip() for x in s.split(':', n)]
...
>>> def parse_line(line):
...     if ':' not in line:
...         return [line.strip(), '']
...     record_type, remainder = munched(line, 1)
...     if record_type == 'time':
...         data = [remainder]
...     else:
...         data = munched(remainder)
...     return record_type, data
...
>>> for guff in """
... hostname:comp1
... time: Fri Jan 28 20:00:02 GMT 2011
... ip:xxx.xxx.xx.xx
... fs:good:45
...     memory   :    bad   :   78
... missing colon
... Mail:good""".splitlines(True):
...    print repr(guff), parse_line(guff)
...
'\n' ['', '']
'hostname:comp1\n' ('hostname', ['comp1'])
'time: Fri Jan 28 20:00:02 GMT 2011\n' ('time', ['Fri Jan 28 20:00:02 GMT 2011'])
'ip:xxx.xxx.xx.xx\n' ('ip', ['xxx.xxx.xx.xx'])
'fs:good:45\n' ('fs', ['good', '45'])
'    memory   :    bad   :   78    \n' ('memory', ['bad', '78'])
'missing colon\n' ['missing colon', '']
'Mail:good' ('Mail', ['good'])
>>>
```

Comment: @Johnsyweb: YAGNI is straight out of "Famous Last Words". It ignores the 256th corollary to Murphy's Law: "If users, developers and pointy-haired bosses can make idiosyncratic changes to a data layout, they will".

Comment: Hence my upvote. However, if the OP owns the data and the parser then there's no more work to do. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the time field always the 2nd line. Why can't you skip it and parse it separately?

Something like

```
for i, line in enumerate(open(rpt, "r").read().splitlines()):
    if i==1: # Special parsing for time: line
        data = line[5:]
    else:
        # your normal parsing logic
```

Comment: I'd have to skip each line that has more than 1 : delimiter and those line with more than 1 : delimiter aren't always in the same place in the file.

Comment: I am having trouble following what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to treat all lines that have more than one : differently (except for the time: line)?

Comment: I suppose the solution would be to check each line for :'s then if it has more than 3 treat it separately? Not sure how to accomplish that though.